# How to batch convert bdsproj to dproj?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

We recently upgraded from Delphi 2006 to Delphi 2007, and the project files changed from `.bdsproj` to `.dproj`.

My research so far indicates that in order to create the `.dproj`, an existing project needs to be opened in the D2007 IDE. We have over 400 `.bdsproj` files so doing this manually is not really practical.

The process I came up with was to open all the projects from the command line using:

```
find . -name *.bdsproj -exec bds.exe -pDelphi -ns -m "{}" ";"
```

This isn't ideal because it is quite slow (wait for BDS to load, wait for compile to happen, wait while BDS closes, ...).

Is there an efficient way to convert multiple `.bdsproj` to `.dproj`?

*Note: The 'find' in the above command line is a UNIX-like find (e.g. MKS or GNU) which searches for files, not the Windows find which searches for text within files.*

Comment: Sad that Embarcadero does not have a command line tool available to do that conversion.

Comment: What's the textual difference between a bdsproj file and its corresponding dproj file? Probably not much, I'd expect. Are they similar enough that a simple program could convert one to the other without having to load Delphi? And they're XML, right? I'm thinking a simple XSLT could transform the lot all at once.

Comment: @Rob, I thought they would be similar too and in some ways they are. But there are differences that make it more than just a translation from one XML to another. Each file contains info that isn't in the other. E.g. dproj contains info from dpr as well as from bdsproj, and the UsePackages setting is in bdsproj is not dproj. Those are just the differences I noticed fairly quickly, there are probably others. Once I saw it wasn't a straight conversion I stopped looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fancier version of the `find` solution using PowerShell. It searches for `bdsproj` files under a specified directory and produces a `bdsgroup` containing all of the projects.

After the script is run, open the `bdsgroup` with D2007 to convert the projects to `dproj`. D2007 also produces a `groupproj`, which seems to be the D2007 equivalent of `bdsgroup`.

Hints:

- Run the script with `-help` to see instructions.
- Start D2007 before opening the `bdsgroup`, it seems to process the projects quicker.
- You don't need to save the projects, opening them is enough to create the `dproj`.

Thanks to:

- **[Ulrich Gerhardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35162/ulrich-gerhardt)** for suggesting the bdsgroup approach.
- **[dangph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60620/dangph)** for help with the PowerShell script.

Here's the script. It works for me :o)

```
Param(
    $path = ".",
    $exclude = "",
    [switch]$help
)

Set-PSDebug -Strict
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# Ensure path is fully qualified and ends with a path delimiter
$path = Join-Path (Resolve-Path $path) ""

# Output file full name ($path\scriptname.bdsproj)
$outfile = Join-Path $path ([IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name, "bdsgroup"))

# Bdsgroup template
$groupXml = [xml]@"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BorlandProject>
    <PersonalityInfo>
        <Option>
            <Option Name="Personality">Default.Personality</Option>
            <Option Name="ProjectType"></Option>
            <Option Name="Version">1.0</Option>
            <Option Name="GUID">{$([guid]::NewGuid().ToString())}</Option>
        </Option>
    </PersonalityInfo>
    <Default.Personality>
        <Projects>
            <Projects Name="Targets"></Projects>
        </Projects>
        <Dependencies/>
    </Default.Personality>
</BorlandProject>
"@

### Functions ###

function ShowUsage()
{
    $myName = Split-Path -Leaf $MyInvocation.ScriptName
    Write-Host "Usage:"
    Write-Host "`t$myName [-path <Path>] [-exclude <Exclude>] [-help]"
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "`t-path <Path>"
    Write-Host "`t`tSpecifies the directory to begin searching for *.bdsproj."
    Write-Host "`t`tPath:" $path
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "`t-exclude <Exclude>"
    Write-Host "`t`tSpecifies a directory to exclude from the search."
    Write-Host "`t`tExclude:" $exclude
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "`t-help"
    Write-Host "`t`tDisplays this message."
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "Output will be written to:"
    Write-Host "`t" $outfile
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "Limitations:"
    Write-Host "`tDoes not support multiple directories for Path or Exclude."
}

# Get the target name.
# e.g. "D:\dev\src\foo.bdsproj" returns "foo.exe"
function GetTarget($bdsproj)
{
    $mainSource = GetMainSource($bdsproj)
    $ext = GetTargetExt($mainSource)
    Split-Path -Leaf ([IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($mainSource, $ext))
}

# Get the relative project path.
# e.g. If path is "D:\dev" then "D:\dev\src\foo.bdsproj" returns "src\foo.bdsproj"
function GetProject($bdsproj)
{
    $prefixLen = $path.Length
    $suffixLen = $bdsproj.Length - $prefixLen
    $bdsproj.Substring($prefixLen, $suffixLen)
}

# Get the fully qualified MainSource (dpr/dpk) path.
# e.g. "D:\dev\src\foo.bdsproj" returns "D:\dev\src\foo.dpr"
function GetMainSource($bdsproj)
{
    $projXml = [xml](Get-Content $bdsproj)
    $mainSource = $projXml.BorlandProject."Delphi.Personality".Source.Source |
        Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "MainSource" }

    $result = Join-Path (Split-Path -Path $bdsproj) $mainSource.InnerText

    if (-not (Test-Path $result))
    {
        throw "No MainSource (dpr/dpk) found for $bdsproj"
    }

    $result
}

# Get the target extension depending on the source type.
function GetTargetExt($mainSource)
{
    $targets = @{"package"="pkg"; "library"="dll"; "program"="exe"}
    $targetType = GetTargetType($mainSource)
    $targets[$targetType]
}

# Read the target type out of the dpr.
function GetTargetType($mainSource)
{
    $name = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($mainSource)
    $pattern = "^\s*(package|library|program)\s+$name;$"
    $matches = (Select-String -Path $mainSource -Pattern $pattern)
    if ($matches -eq $null)
    {
        throw "Unknown target type (pkg/dll/exe) for $mainSource"
    }
    $matches.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
}

# Add a project entry to groupXml.
# e.g. <Projects Name="foo.exe">src\foo.bdsproj</Projects>
function AddProject($target, $project)
{
    $node = $groupXml.CreateElement("Projects")
    $node.SetAttribute("Name", $target)
    $node.InnerText = $project
    $groupXml.BorlandProject."Default.Personality".Projects.AppendChild($node) | Out-Null

    $targets = $groupXml.BorlandProject."Default.Personality".Projects.Projects |
        Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Targets" }
    $targets.InnerText = $targets.InnerText + " " + $target
}

### Main ###

if ($help)
{
    ShowUsage
}
else
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include "*.bdsproj" -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $exclude -eq "" -or $_.FullName -notmatch $exclude } |
    ForEach-Object { AddProject (GetTarget $_.FullName) (GetProject $_.FullName) }

    $groupXml.OuterXml | Out-File -Encoding "UTF8" $outfile
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can open several projects at once. Even using drag and drop.

- Select 40 projects
- Drag them to the IDE
- Click yes 40 times
- Save all
- close all
- Repeat until finished.

Comment: Seems efficient enough for a one time task.

Comment: only limitation: duplicate project names in a project group are not allowed - I regret using project names like 'Unittests' here and there, the IDE keeps on bleeping at me ;)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use a command line similar to your `find` (and maybe a little Delphi programm) to create a *.bdsgroup file with all projects and open that in D2007.